# Calendar Appointment View

Tags: list-view, calendar, view, sharepoint-calendar, date-time

Am looking for some help please with how to amend a calendar i've created to show Public Holidays so it shows the title only for an appointment and excludes the start and finish times.

[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can apply css to hide information about time.

Steps:

1. Open calendar's month view
2. Click Edit page
3. Add Script editor webpart
4. Insert the code below into editor

   ```
   <style>.ms-acal-time{display: none;}</style>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve this is to make the even (in your case holiday) and "All Day Event" (this will surely work) or try to make **Start Time and End Time as "Date Only"** columns. If you are not able to modify settings of these 2 columns, then create 2 fields with date only and use them as start time and end time.

Comment: "All Day Event" works!